# How do i represent an infinite series as an integral? (complex numbers)

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

My calculus book has nothing on complex numbers so here i am.

$$ e^z = \sum_0^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!} $$

Given the above function as an example , can someone take me through the steps as to how i would represent it as an integral? and perhaps offer an extra example where i don't know the function , just the sum?

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: Are you asking how to convert the sum into an integral?

Comment: yes , if possible, i am showing what this infinite sum is (e^z) but my ideal example would be i am given an infinite sum , and i convert that sum into an integral

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are familiar with [Taylor's Theorem and Taylor's Expansion of Analytic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series). See Analytic functions. Now the term $f^{(n)}(z)$ can be expressed by the help of [Cauchy Integral Formula for $n^{th}$ derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) as, $$a_nn!=f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz$$ $\forall n=0,1,2...$. Notations are defined in the links.